# Asynchronicity with GET requests in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, http, asynchronous, axios

I'm still new to VueJS. So i'm trying to make a GET request to the git API. At first I make a request sorting users by follower count, which retrieves me an array in descending order of user's logins. After that I make another GET request to each of these login values to get more in-depth data such as avatar url, repositories count, etc. The problem is, and I usually still struggle with asynchronicity, as some of the requests go faster than others, my new array of objects gets out of sequence in terms of followers count. I'm trying to do a sort() method but I can't seem to figure out the sequence in which each function is being run in the js flow. Can someone help me out?

Here's both the components i'm using for this:

Home.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Devfinder</h1>
      <p>Find relevant developers from Github</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <SearchBars :fetchLogins="fetchLogins" />
      <CardList :cards="cards" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CardList from "./CardList";
import SearchBars from "./SearchBars";
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "Home",
  data() {
    return {
      loginList: [],
      cardList: [],
      cards: [],
      page: 1,
    };
  },
  components: {
    SearchBars,
    CardList,
  },
  methods: {
    fetchLogins(language, location) {
      axios
        .get(
          `https://api.github.com/search/users?q=location:${location}+language:${language}&sort=followers&order=desc&page=${this.page}&per_page=8`,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: "***",
            },
          }
        )
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
          this.loginList = res.data.items.map((item) => item.login);
          console.log(this.loginList);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
        .then(() => this.setCardInfo())
        .then(() => this.cards = this.cardList.sort((a,b) => b.followers - a.followers));
    },
    setCardInfo() {
      let newCardsArray = [];
      this.cards = [];
      this.cardList = [];
      // Zera o state de cards e itera o array loginList fazendo um GET request e criando o objeto para o array cards
      this.loginList.forEach((login) =>
        axios
          .get(`https://api.github.com/users/${login}`, {
            headers: {
              Authorization: "***",
            },
          })
          .then((res) => {
            const user = res.data;
            const cardObject = {
              id: user.id,
              name: user.name,
              avatar: user.avatar_url,
              bio: user.bio,
              followers: user.followers,
              repositories: user.public_repos,
            };
            newCardsArray.push(cardObject);
          })
      );
      // Por causa da assincronicidade, alguns objetos, mesmo com mais seguidores, acabam ficando atrás na ordem do array
      // invoco um sort() em ordem descendente
      this.cardList = newCardsArray;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

and my SearchBars component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form @submit="onSubmit">
      <p>Tech/Lang</p>
      <input type="text" v-model="language" placeholder="Type a technology or language" />
      <p>Location</p>
      <input type="text" v-model="location" placeholder="Type the desired location" />
      <input type="submit" value="FIND" />
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "SearchBars",
  data() {
      return {
          language: '',
          location: ''
      }
  },
  methods: {
      onSubmit(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          this.fetchLogins(this.language, this.location);
      }
  },
  props:["fetchLogins", "getCardInfo"]
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this isn't working is because neither of your functions are asynchronous. It doesn't matter for `fetchLogins`, since nothing is waiting on it. However, since, in `fetchLogins`, you're waiting on the call to `setCardInfo`, you need `setCardInfo` to be asynchronous. What's happening is, in this line:

```js
.then(() => this.setCardInfo())
```

Your `.then` chain starts up `this.setCardInfo`, but doesn't wait before moving onto the next `.then` in the chain. This is beacause `setCardInfo` does not return a Promise, so the `.then` resolves immedaitely.

---

There are two ways to do this. You could keep with how your code is currently organized, and make `this.setCardInfo` return a Promise; or; you could change to `async`/`await` syntax (which is the same under the hood), and make your code much more readable.

When you define an `async` function, all you're really doing is wrapping it all in a `return new Promise`, where that function's return value is the value of `resolve`. So, that means that you can `.then` that function. **But wait!!** When a function is asynchronous, you can use the special keyword, `await` to tell the function, *"run this line, wait for it to finish, and then keep going"* — what you're doing is essentially `.then`-ing the rest of the function, but without having to chain another `.then` and add *another* level of indentation.

Another thing you can make use of in your case is `Promise.all`: you pass it an array of Promises (which, as we now know, are what `async` functions return under the hood!), and it will only resolve **its** Promise once all of the functions in the array have resolved. So, you can do something like,

```js
async function myFunc(arr) {
  const responses = await Promise.all(arr.map(async item => {
    const res = await fetch('api', { body: item });
    return await res.json();
  });
}
```

and you'll end up with an array of the `arr`'s items' responses' JSON. What it's doing is simply creating an array of unresolved promises, and `Promise.all` simply waits for them to all resolve. If any of them reject, then `Promise.all` will reject. So, when I used that paradigm here, I put it in a `try`/`catch` within the `map`, so you can hopefully deal with it on a per-card basis.

Take a look at my proposed solution (this is just the `methods` section):

```js
methods: {
    fetchLogins: async function(language, location) {
      let res;
      try {
        res = await axios.get(
          `https://api.github.com/search/users?q=location:${location}+language:${language}&sort=followers&order=desc&page=${this.page}&per_page=8`,
          { headers: { Authorization: "90fa62d4dee8b02d363d83fccac86f3b7536492c" } }
        );
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        // deal w/ error, so the code below (dependent
        // on 'res') doesn't run. Or just let it err out.
        // up to you.
      }
      
      // None of this is async, so it doesn't need an await
      console.log(res.data);
      this.loginList = res.data.items.map(item => item.login);
      console.log(this.loginList);

      // Run the other function
      this.cards = [];
      this.cardList = [];

      // Keeping this as a separate function, since I don't know how you're
      // going to use it, but it could totally be be copied here.
      // "this.cardList // = await Promise.all ..." is really just one
      // line down there. Paste it here if you aren't gonna need it as a
      // separate function
      await this.setCardInfo();

      this.cards = this.cardList.sort((a, b) => b.followers = a.followers);
    },
    setCardInfo: async function () {
      this.cardList = await Promise.all(this.loginList.map(async login => {
        let res;
        try {
          res = axios.get(
            `https://api.github.com/users/${login}`,
            { headers: { Authorization: "90fa62d4dee8b02d363d83fccac86f3b7536492c" } }
          );
        } catch (err) {
          console.errror(err);
          // Deal w/ error (return undefined? "couldn't find user's info"?)
        }

        const user = res.data;
        const cardObject = {
          id: user.id,
          name: user.name,
          avatar: user.avatar_url,
          bio: user.bio,
          followers: user.followers,
          respositories: user.public_repos
        };

        // Resolve the Promise for this iteration of the map funciton
        return cardObject;
      }));
    },
  },
```

I'm not 100% sure this will work for you, but I don't think I've changed any of what the code actually does, so it should. If not, I hope my explanations of Promises and `async`/`await` prove to be a stepping stone.

I recommend checking out the ever-fantastic MDN for resources on this. They even have a [starter guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) that you can read, so you don't have to simply read formal documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use newCardsArray variable and just push cardObject into your cardList.
It is assigning empty value before the API call has done.